# Undefined control sequence caption

Tags: errors, captions, subcaption

When I compile document that has such code:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{emdash}{~--- }
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=emdash,font=onehalfspacing,position=bottom}
\captionsetup{%
    singlelinecheck=off,
    skip=2pt,
    justification=centering,
}

% ...

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{test.png}
    \caption{Text here}
\end{figure}
```

I get error `line 54: Undefined control sequence. \caption{Text here}`.
How to resolve this issue?

P.S. Without caption all works properly.

Comment: Your fragment is not really usefull, but `labelsep` should be `labelsep=endash` most likely. Also the `setspace` package is missing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely the error is `labelsep=emdash`.

Either the declaration has been forgotten or it's easy to define `emdash`:

```
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{emdash}{\textemdash}
```

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{setspace}


\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{emdash}{\textemdash}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=emdash,font=onehalfspacing,position=bottom}
\captionsetup{%
  singlelinecheck=off,
  skip=2pt,
  justification=centering,
}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{ente}
    \caption{Text here}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have such lines in code: `\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{emdash}{~--- }
%\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=emdash,font=onehalfspacing,position=bottom}`, When `\captionsetup` is uncomment, all works properly, but when I uncomment it I get error `Undefined control sequence.`

Comment: @0x1337: Then show us the code, not fragments only

Comment: Thank you! The problem was in the order of `\captionsetup`s.

Comment: @0x1337 The order of `\captionsetup` is irrelevant, so I doubt that the problem was in the order. If it was anyway, this might be a bug in my `caption` package so I would like to have a document which actually reproduces the problem. (This is still missing here, and still no-one except you knows what the problem was.)

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt, I'm sorry, I can not share with the full document. It's very big and messy :(

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: I missed the comment about the order of `captionsetup` options unfortunately, otherwise I would have responded to the O.P.

Comment: @0x1337: We don't need your full document --just the minimal version of it that produced the error above